# GWT button click event

Tags: gwt

i have one window panel in my project.
and i add one button to it.
when i click the button,i want two event to fire.
one event is to hide that window,which i achieve through

```
 Button button = new Button("click");
button.addListener(new ButtonListenerAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(Button button, EventObject e) {
            hide();
            super.onClick(button, e);
        }

    });
Window.add(button);
```

and second i want to pop up another window at the same time on the same button click..what to do?
help me out

Comment: Do you want to reuse the same Window object?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Are you trying to hide one `Window` and show another? What are you calling `hide()` on? Can we see more code?

Comment: no i don't wan't to reuse the same object.
and by calling hide() means Window.hide().sorry for incomplete code.

Comment: thank you for help.i have done it.
i just put condition if(Window.isVisible()) and put appropreate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should solve your problem :

```
   final boolean evenClick = false;
   Button button = new Button("click");
   button.addListener(new ButtonListenerAdapter(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(Button button, EventObject e) {

        if (!evenClick) {
            hide();
        super.onClick(button, e);
                         }
         else {
       //DO YOUR SECOND CLICK STUFF
                }
        evenClick = !evenClick;     

    }

});
Window.add(button);
```

Comment: Instead of having a flag (`evenClick`) it would probably be best to check which (if any) window in currently visible and then from there show one and hide the other.

Comment: enrybo-please elaborate your answer.i don't get it.